# Python dynamic datetime periods

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I'm working on coding a HAR-RV volatility model where I regress daily, weekly, and monthly data to predict tomorrow's daily volatility.  I have 6 years of daily data that I would like to backtest against.  At first, I thought this would be quite simple - I used pandas asfreq to transform my daily data to weekly and monthly to calculate daily, weekly, and monthly pct_change to begin the analysis.  The issue is that I am trying to find a function in python that will allow me to calculate a monthly and weekly pct_change for each daily data point so that on 1/24/15 I will have week beginning 1/17/2015 (-7 days) and month beginning 12/25/2014 (-30 days) and for daily data point 1/23/15 I will have week beginning 1/16/2015 (-7 days) and month beginning 12/24/2014 (-30 days), etc.

However, by using asfreq('W') and asfreq('M') I am getting 31 daily data points for each month (OK) 1 monthly data point for each month (not OK) and 4 weekly data points for each month (not OK).  I need 31 daily points, 31 weekly points, and 31 monthly points for each month.

Any guidance on how I can achieve corresponding weekly and monthly pct_change for each daily datetime?  Here is the code that I am currently using:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from zipline.data.loader import load_bars_from_yahoo
start = pd.Timestamp('2009-07-26')
end = pd.Timestamp('2015-01-18')
data = zp.utils.factory.load_from_yahoo(
    stocks=['USO'],
    start=start,
    end=end,
    )
daily = data
weekly = daily.asfreq('W-FRI')
monthly = daily.asfreq('M')`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `asfreq` method is used to *reindex* your data. That is to say, it bins it over different time periods.

What you want to do is calculating *rolling* statistics.
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#moving-rolling-statistics-moments

Here is an implementation using a custom lambda function and a `rolling_apply` that seems to do what you want:

```
from pandas import Series, date_range
import numpy as np

# Generate some synthetic price data
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000), index=date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000))
ts = ts.cumsum() + 100
ts.plot()

# Define a function to calculate percent change over an x-day period 
rollingChange = lambda x: 100*(x[-1]-x[0])/x[0]

# Use rolling_apply to calculate 7 and 30 day rolling prcnt_change
week = pd.rolling_apply(ts, 7, rollingChange)
month = pd.rolling_apply(ts, 30, rollingChange)
```

Here is a nbviewer link for some more details:
http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/twowheelmotion/70e8f114b208c194ac8b

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have adjusted close prices ('adj_close') as a column  in sequential order, you could do something like the below.

```
    df['daily_performance'] = df.groupby('Ticker').adj_close.pct_change().fillna(0)
    df['5_day_performance'] = df.groupby('Ticker').adj_close.pct_change(periods=5).fillna(0)
    df['21_day_performance'] = df.groupby('Ticker').adj_close.pct_change(periods=21).fillna(0)
```

If you don't have a ticker column with multiple stocks, you can get rid of "groupby('Ticker).  5 days/week on average and 21 trading days per month on average, thus, the 5 and 21 above.